# ionic start error self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, hybrid-mobile-app

someone can help me for resolve this problem.

When I run this command in CMD (as admin)
`ionic start projectName blank`

I get to this problem

```
C:\ionic start firstApp blank
√ Creating directory .\firstApp - done!
[INFO] Fetching app base (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-
base/archive/master.tar.gz)
× Downloading - failed!
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

**My ionic info:**

***cli packages:***

@ionic/cli-utils: 1.6.0

ionic (Ionic CLI): 3.6.0

***System:***

Node : v8.2.1

OS : Windows 10

npm : 5.3.0

**Other Information:**

this's my first experience with ionic